Safely using a "switching power supply" with 220V raw wire input
This article features something called a "switching power supply", which transforms a 220V AC current from regular european power outlets to a DC power output, which can then be used to power DC motors. There are many differnt amp outputs available for this "fonte" model (up to 60amp at 3V), which made me think it's suitable for applications that need to concurrently drive many small motors at the same time in a stable fashion.
However, I am unsure about the power input, since it's essentially just a screw that you can wind a raw wire around and then screw on tightly. For lower voltages this would be fine, but I worry that it's dangerous to directly connect a wire from a power outlet to an input like this without proper insulation. How is something like this intended to be used exactly? Do alternatives exist that have the same functionality but are safer to use?

The general rule for 220VAC stuff is that everything should be insulated. Look for UL or at least CE marking on the product, I see nothing resembling such on the pictures in that link. Meaning the product might be illegal for export at least to North America or Europe. Conclusion: don't buy electronics from vendors with a very poor reputation such as Amazon or Aliexpress.

The power supply is meant to be inside an enclosure which prevents anyone from coming into contact with exposed mains terminals. These are not intended for using as-is on your table or mounted on wall or product.
From then on, it's about how to safely wire it inside the enclosure.
Usually you would not just take a wire and place it under the screw as that would be unsafe. You would use some kind of crimped terminal that is either shaped like a fork so you can slide it under the screw, or shaped like a ring if the screw can be taken off to go through the terminal, so it will not move anywhere dangerously if the screw comes loose. In a pinch, maybe just a simple crimped termination ferrule can be used.
In some units there will be a plastic cover over the mains input terminals to further make servicing inside an enclosure safer.
I bet power supplies like this but with mains inlet connector exists, but they are still not meant to be used as standalone units without an additional metal case.

That kind of screw terminal is common on UL and ISO certified power supplies. There is a barrier between terminals, and it's likely more than the 1 mm barrier required for 220 volts, just by looking at the picture. There is also a plastic insulator between terminal screws that would also increase the distance.
So I'm not 100% sure that it would be safe because I don't have the supply in my hand, it's likely not been tested through an NRTL so I would not think it was safe, typically power supply sourced from cheap manufacturing will not have certifications or fake certifications so check the certifications on the supply, if it has the appropriate UL or equivalent certs, then you are good to go.
